# cons, list and mpair in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the following code and its evaluation as comment:

```
(require scheme/mpair)

(list)                   ;; '()
(mlist)                  ;; '()

(cons 'un (list))        ;; '(un)
(list 'un (list))        ;; '(un ())

(mcons 'un (mlist))      ;; (mcons 'un '())
(mlist 'un (mlist))      ;; (mcons 'un (mcons '() '()))
```

My questions:

1. why doesn't the 3rd expression return `'()`, instead of `'(un . ())`?
2. why don't the 5th expression and the the 6th expression return the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general example, `(list x y z)` is an abbreviation for `(cons x (cons y (cons z empty)))`. And `(list)` is an empty list, i.e. `empty`. So `(list 'un (list))` is just an abbreviation for `(cons 'un (cons empty empty))`  - I.e. a list with two elements in it: the symbol `'un` and an empty list. `mlist` similarly is an abbreviation for a sequence of `mcons`'es onto `empty` at the very end.